# Tangent bundle for orthogonal and isotropic Grassmannians

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, grassmannians, projective-varieties, cotangent-bundles

We will work over $\mathbb C$. Let us consider a $n$-dimensional vector space $V$, then we define the $k$-th Grassmannian as
$$
\mathbb G(k,V):=\{W \subset V : \dim W=k\}.
$$
Then consider a non-degenerate quadratic form on $V$, we write $q: V \times V \to \mathbb C$ if it is symmetric, $\omega: V \times V \to \mathbb C$ if it is skew-symmetric (in this case $n$ is even).
Then one can define, respectively, the orthogonal $k$-th Grassmannian
$$
\mathbb O\mathbb G(k, V)=\{q\text{-isotropic }W \subset V : \dim W=k\}
$$
and the isotropic $k$-th Grassmannian
$$
\mathbb I\mathbb G(k, V)=\{\omega\text{-isotropic }W \subset V : \dim W=k\}.
$$

In the "classic" case, we know that the tangent bundle is given by
$$
T_{\mathbb G(k,V)}=\mathcal S^\vee \otimes \mathcal Q
$$
where $\mathcal S$ and $\mathcal Q$ denote the universal subbundle and the universal quotient bundle, following Eisenbud and Harris. When $\dim V=2m$, then a similar expression is known for $\mathbb O \mathbb G(m,V)$ and $\mathbb I \mathbb G(m,V)$:
$$
T_{\mathbb O \mathbb G(m,V)}=\wedge^2 \mathcal U^\vee, \quad T_{\mathbb I \mathbb G(m,V)}=S^2 \mathcal U^\vee
$$
where $\mathcal U$ is given by the restriction of the tautological bundle on $\mathbb G(n,V)$.

Finally the question: are there similar expressions of the tangent bundles for the other orthogonal and isotropic Grassmannians? Also a reference would be enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tangent bundle to the orthogonal Grassmannian fits into an exact sequence
$$
0 \to T_{\mathrm{OG}(k,V)} \to \mathcal{S}^\vee \otimes \mathcal{Q} \to S^2\mathcal{S}^\vee \to 0.
$$
Taking into account an exact sequence
$$
0 \to \mathcal{S}^\perp/\mathcal{S} \to \mathcal{Q} \to \mathcal{S}^\vee \to 0
$$
one can obtain an exact sequence
$$
0 \to \mathcal{S} \otimes (\mathcal{S}^\perp/\mathcal{S}) \to T_{\mathrm{OG}(k,V)} \to \wedge^2\mathcal{S}^\vee \to 0.
$$
A similar description exists for the symplectic isotropic Grassmannian.

Comment: Is there a reference for such results?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: I really can't understand the proof you write. I think that the first sequence is the tangent sequence
$$
0 \to T_{\mathbb O \mathbb G(k,V)} \to T_{\mathbb G(k,V)}|_{\mathbb O \mathbb G(k,V)} \to \mathcal N_{\mathbb O \mathbb G(k,V)|\mathbb G(k,V)} \to 0,
$$
but I can't really understand where the second sequence come from.

Comment: The second sequence is a combination of the tautological sequence $$0 \to \mathcal{S} \to V \otimes \mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{Q} \to 0$$ and of its dual $$0 \to \mathcal{S}^\perp \to V \otimes \mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{S}^\vee \to 0$$.

Comment: Dual in which sense? $\mathcal S^\perp = \mathcal Q^\vee$?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: Ok, I feel a bit stupid, but I cannot understand what combination of these two sequences should lead me to the second one you wrote in the first answer. May I use snake lemma argument or something like that?

Comment: Yes, there is a morphism from the tautological sequence to its dual, and the snake lemma applied to the obtained bicomplex gives the second sequence in the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128759/discussion-between-bobech-and-sasha).

Comment: I've never used such tools, so forgive me if I will write something stupid. My first idea is to understand what happens over a point $[\mathbb P W]$. The tautological sequence and its dual looks like
$$
0 \to W \to V \to V/W \to 0
$$
$$
0 \to (V/W)^\vee = W^\perp \to V^\vee=V \to W^\vee \to 0
$$
The morphism of sequences should send $W \to W^\perp$, $V/W=(W^\perp)^\vee \to W^\vee$, but I cannot understand what it does on the middle term

Comment: On the middle terms it is the isomorphism $V \to V^\vee$ given by the quadratic (or symplectic) form.

Comment: Now I can see how it works! Thank you so much!
Last question, I promise. How do you know that the normal bundle $\mathcal N_{\mathbb O \mathbb G(k,V)|\mathbb G(k,V)}$ is $S^2 \mathcal S^\vee$? It is common knowledge or it is proved somewhere?

Comment: To understand the normal bundle just note that $\mathrm{OG}(k,V) \subset \mathrm{G}(k,V)$ is the zero locus of the global section of $S^2\mathcal{S}^\vee$ on $\mathrm{OG}(k,V)$ (given by the quadratic form), which has the expected codimension, hence the normal bundle is the restriction of the bundle whose zero locus you considered.

Comment: I've never used this approach of zero locus of global sections, where can I find a reference?

Comment: Maybe in the book of Eisenbud?